# Uses for thick "country-style" phyllo?

Tags: middle-eastern-cuisine, pastry

I bought a few boxes of Phyllo (Fillo) that is described as Horiatiko / Country Style - Extra-Thick #10. Extra-thick is definitely relative; it is probably twice as thick as normal phyllo but still paper-thin. The first thing I did with it was to make a spinach/manouri/feta filling seasoned with ras al hanout, brushed the phyllo with butter, rolled them up and baked til golden. It was good, but not nearly as flaky as normal phyllo.

So my questions are (1) is there something I should be doing to have it come out flakier or is that just how the country-style is? (2) are there particular applications where the country-style is considered preferable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's meant that way. Good for pies, etc.

[See this link on phyllo](http://www.saveur.com/article/Techniques/Phyllo-Finds) types if you like.

Comment: Great link, thank you! So I basically made hortopita in a different form factor :).